# Frameworks for tagging user interview notes?

Tags: user-research, research

I've had some success, and interesting insights, applying a very simple and custom tagging system to user interview notes. An example of this would be labeling feedback as quote, praise, pain point, interface, data, search, ect. Are there any formal tagging frameworks or taxonomy's for labeling interview notes?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any framework, though I'm sure many of us have developed our own. I start with these base category/tag sets and add if the product demands it.

1. **Feedback type**

   - Bug
   - Feature request
   - Observation
2. **Sentiment**

   - Positive
   - Neutral
   - Negative

"Observation" + "Positive" gives you praise and + "Negative" gives you pain point.

Cross-reference those against **Product** and **Feature area** and you can do some interesting analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are looking for tools to do this, but here is one called Reframer by Optimal Workshop. https://www.optimalworkshop.com/reframer

Answer (score 0):

No matter what you use, remember that you may use them to present the results to stakeholders shortly. Those stakeholders don't care the research process, they don't have much time, and too many, or unclear labels may be considered as a waste of time by them.

I don't know the context of your research, but I would suggest instead of looking for seemly sophisticated frameworks, go with the most simple solution. For example, just label user satisfaction with "happy", or label any pain point as "mad", just an example. But what I am saying is don't let UX jargon get in the way of the communication between your and the stakeholders. Remember they are your users, too.